# Apache2 'Server' header reports wrong openSSL version

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, openssl, ssl

Does anyone know where the Apache 'Server' header pulls the openSSL version from (file location/directory)? I am expecting openssl-1.0.1j but apache is reporting openssl-1.0.1g (system's openssl version).

I compiled apache with these options:

```
--enable-ssl
--with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1j
```

**ldd mod_ssl.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff07357000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f94d9895000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f94d962b000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f94d924f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f94d9032000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f94d8c9f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000360d200000)
```

**ls -lh /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0**

```
/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 -> /opt/openssl-1.0.1j/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

**ls -lh /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0**

```
/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> /opt/openssl-1.0.1j/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

**curl --head hostname**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 15:27:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

After much digging through the Apache source, I found that that particular part of the `Server` response header ultimately comes from calling [`SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/SSLeay_version.html); which reports the version of the OpenSSL libraries (as opposed to the version in the OpenSSL headers).

So if that's the case, **and** the `mod_ssl.so` shows that it *should* be dynamically loading the expected versions of the OpenSSL libraries, where is the old version coming from?

The only things I can think of are:

- *a)* the Apache you compiled is not the one that is running and responding to `curl`; perhaps the system/default Apache is running?
- *b)* the Apache that is running is loading its dynamic/shared modules from a different directory than the `mod_ssl.so` you examined in your post?

The most common scenario I've seen is the first: the manually compiled Apache ends up installing into *e.g.* `/usr/local/apache2/bin/`, but the system/default Apache is in a different location, and the startup scripts use that system/default location, rather than the new Apache executable you compiled/installed.